# Getting pixel color from a full screen directx game in C

Tags: c, colors, directx, pixel

So I'm trying to get the pixel color of the mouse position from a game called "Gunz"...

As far as I know, Gunz works on DirectX.

I tried to make it work on window mode using GDI, I got the pixel colors,

But when I use the full screen DirectX I only get white, example:

Red: 255

Green: 255

Blue: 255

---

Here's my code -

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

FARPROC pGetPixel;

HINSTANCE _hGDI = LoadLibrary("gdi32.dll");


while(1) {

if(_hGDI){
    pGetPixel = GetProcAddress(_hGDI, "GetPixel");
    HDC _hdc = GetDC(NULL);


if(_hdc){
    POINT _cursor;
    GetCursorPos(&_cursor);
    COLORREF _color = (*pGetPixel) (_hdc, _cursor.x, _cursor.y);
    int _red = GetRValue(_color);
    int _green = GetGValue(_color);
    int _blue = GetBValue(_color);

    printf("Cursor Pos: X: %d, Y: %d.\n", _cursor.x, _cursor.y);
    printf("Red: %d\n", _red);
    printf("Green: %d\n", _green);
    printf("Blue: %d\n", _blue);
    }
}
Sleep(1000);
}

FreeLibrary(_hGDI);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: http://www.powerbasic.com/support/forums/Forum6/HTML/001070.html

Comment: Actually it is VB, if you can help me with any example code for C it would be perfect...
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why not take a screenshot in full screen mode, then get the pixel color from the picture?